# Higher-Order Functions in K?

Tags: kframework

Is it possible to write higher-order functions in K?

Particularly, things like `Map` and `Fold`, where I traverse a structure and apply a function to every element.

For example, if I have a list:

```
A ~> B ~> C
```

and I want to map a function `F` to every element of the list:

```
F A ~> F B ~> F C
```

Or maybe produce a fold:

```
F A (F B (F C))
```

where `F` is `[function, functional]` and is meant to evaluate, not be there syntactically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know is advance what functions you want to be using in a higher order fashion, you can approximate this with something like:

```
syntax MapFunction ::= "foo"
syntax KItem ::= MapFunction "(" KItem ")" [function]

rule foo(...) => ...

syntax List ::= map(List, MapFunction) [function]
rule map(.List, _) => .List
rule map(ListItem(K) L, F) => ListItem(F(K)) map(L, F)
```

I recognize this is not ideal since it's not really a higher order function and you have to be explicitly aware of every function you intend to use this way and write it in a different fashion, but it's a decent workaround if you just need something quick and dirty in a couple places in the semantics.

As for the rest of your question, we would love to support higher order functions more generally, but we do not yet.

Comment: Note that you can still get things like function composition going using this approach, by saying something like `syntax MapFunction ::= MapFunction "." MapFunction` and `rule (F . G) (X) => F (G (X))`. As @Dwight said, we don't support them being properly polymorphic yet (so no type-checking your function composition at kompile-time, instead it will just get stuck at runtime), but it's slowly being worked on.